# Change pagelayout on page - No drop down

Tags: 2010, page-layout

I'm facing an issue where when I set a page in edit mode and want to change the pagelayout I can click the **Page Layout** button in the ribbon, but the dropdown list from which you're supposed to pick the new pagelayout doesn't appear.

I couldn't find much relating on google. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any javascript errors and/or have you changed the z-index of anything? Check with firefox/chrome/ie8 and ie9. It might narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of my problem to this.

Through the past couple months I've deployed and removed custom pagelayouts, and something happened so I could no longer override existing pagelayouts, but I could still override the file directly in the file system. This left redundant and invalid IDs to previous pagelayouts with the same URL.

This means that the SharePoint ribbon tries to load unexisting content and thus errors and cannot show the dropdown. By cleaning up my solution and my SharePoint this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you do not have permissiosn to change the page layout, or the page is checked out by another user. It is possible to get into edit mode even if another user has checked out the page.